# can't interact with external harddrives

Tags: mount

I have built a Linux/Ubuntu computer with 120 GB SSD and two WesternDigital Blue Sata Hardrives. Ubuntu installed well and is operating well but I can't see or access the two WesternDigital hardrives.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1196765/edit) your post with the result of `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

Download gparted and see if there are your drives or not?
If yes but not showing then you can try formatting those drives.